# Should i use proxy models in django?

Tags: django, django-models, relational-database

im here trying to start a new project, in django
and i came across this problem, while creating the models
My users will be different types of users, so i was thinking, should i use proxy models for it?
because here is how it´s going to be the realtionship between them.
i will have a client, and a personal trainer, and the admin of course, but the problem here is that the client is going to have a `ForeignKey` with personal trainer, my main question is, can i create in a proxy model an extra field where i establish the relationship with personal trainer proxy model?

If not, is there any other way that i can aproach this type of situation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No.  As far as I know a Proxy Model only changes the *behavior* of a model.  You can add new methods only.  If you want to add new fields it must be a Concrete Model.

You should create a new model class which inherits from `AbstractUser`.  Then you can either add a `type` field which can be "client" or "personal_trainer" or "whatever".  Or you could use a `OneToOne` field to have a UserProfile associated w/ your user - a different profile for "clients" or "personal_trainers" or "whatevers".

Comment: that would be an option, but i think i figured it out, after a good night sleep, what i did was, created a user class that inherits from `AbstractUser` and then created a class that inherits from `User` with a `class Meta: abstract=True` and then i created the 2 models `Client` `PersonalTrainer`

Comment: i really dont know if this was the "right" method, but for now it works i guess XD

Comment: @filipe do `Client` and `PersonalTrainer` inherent from `User`? Then how do you manage auth? I mean `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`